# How isolate users data stored in SQL DB in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have problem to find the best way how isolate users data stored in db.

Now if i login and access to my profile i can see data loaded from db.

example `.../myprofile/PeterM`

but if i manualy change address to `.../myprofile/MartaM` i see data stored in db for user marta 
how can i isolate members data.

Thanks for my maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check that the user who is accessing the data is allowed to do so. Don't rely on just the querystring.

So for instance, instead of performing your database lookup based on the username in the querystring, get the information based off the currently authenticated user.

If I'm logged in as Brandon, then `GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);` should always return my information, regardless of whose name is passed in to the controller action.

Or just check that the username you're retrieving is the same as `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`